# Java servlet two attributes one servlet and one redirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

this is my first question here. And I am sorry if it's already answered but I don't know how to ask?
My problem is that on web page I have big table and I am doing some sorting list. I create  list with "onselect" send value to servlet.
Servlet need to accept first or second attribute and than create new session.setAttribute.
Maybe if you look at my code you can understand what I mean:

servlet code:

```
package servlets;

import baza.Baza;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "FilterServlet", urlPatterns = {"/FilterServlet"})
public class FilterServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filterDobavljac = request.getParameter("grupa1");
    String filterKategorija = request.getParameter("grupa2");

    System.out.println("FilterDobavljac:" + "'" + filterDobavljac + "'");
    System.out.println("FilterKategorija:" + "'" + filterKategorija + "'");

    HttpSession sesija = request.getSession(true);

    if (!filterDobavljac.equals("ALL") || !filterDobavljac.equals("")) {

        sesija.setAttribute("proizvodi", Baza.FiltriranjeProizvodaGrupa1(filterDobavljac).values());
    }

    if (!filterKategorija.equals("ALL") || !filterKategorija.equals("")) {

        sesija.setAttribute("proizvodi", Baza.FiltriranjeProizvodaGrupa2(filterKategorija).values());
    }

    System.out.println("FilterDobavljac:" + "'" + filterDobavljac + "'");
    System.out.println("FilterKategorija:" + "'" + filterKategorija + "'");
    response.sendRedirect("proizvodi.jsp");
}
}

System.out.println  - are here only for fast debug
```

Part from database class:

```
public static Hashtable<Integer,Proizvod> FiltriranjeProizvodaGrupa1(String filter){
    System.out.println(filter);
    Hashtable<Integer,Proizvod> proizvodiFiltered = new Hashtable<Integer, Proizvod>();

    if (!filter.equals("ALL")) {
        for (Proizvod p : proizvodi.values()) {
            if (p.getGrupa1().getNaziv().equals(filter)) {
                proizvodiFiltered.put(p.getId(), p);
            }
        }return proizvodiFiltered;
    }
    return proizvodi;
}
```

The code is the same for another Hashtable
And here is web part:

```
        <form action="FilterServlet" method="post" name="productForm">

        <table class="center style">
            <tr>
                <th>Bar kod</th>
                <th>Sifra</th>
                <th>Naziv</th>
                <th>kolicina</th>
                <th>Dobavljac</th>
                <th>Kategorija</th>
                <th>Cena</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <c:forEach items="${proizvodi}" var="m">
                            <option style="display:none"></option>
                            <option value="${m.barkod}">
                                ${m.barkod}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <c:forEach items="${proizvodi}" var="m">
                            <option style="display:none"></option>
                            <option value="${m.sifra}">
                                ${m.sifra}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <c:forEach items="${proizvodi}" var="m">
                            <option style="display:none"></option>
                            <option value="${m.naziv}">
                                ${m.naziv}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="grupa1" name="grupa1" onchange="return setValue();">
                        <option style="display:none"></option>
                        <option>ALL</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${grupa1Filter}" var="g1">
                            <option value="${g1}">
                                ${g1}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="grupa2" name="grupa2" onchange="return setValue();">
                        <option style="display:none"></option>
                        <option>ALL</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${grupa2Filter}" var="g2">
                            <option value="${g2}">
                                ${g2}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${proizvodi}" var="p">
                <tr>
                    <td>${p.barkod}</td>
                    <td>${p.sifra}</td>
                    <td>${p.naziv}</td>
                    <td>${p.kolicina}</td>
                    <td>${p.grupa1.naziv}</td>
                    <td>${p.grupa2.naziv}</td>
                    <td>${p.cena}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="btn_dropdown">
    </form>
</body>
```

I get two different attributes, it's not a problem.
Problem is in servlet when I select first attribute "grupa1" dropdown list i get empty table but when i select second "grupa2" everything is ok.

JavaScript code:

```
function setValue() {
document.getElementById("dropdown").value = document.getElementById("grupa1").value;
document.getElementById("dropdown").value = document.getElementById("grupa2").value;
document.productForm.submit();
return true;
}
```

Comment: missing javascript for "setValue()", please include